# Cannot receive Uninstall broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to detect the uninstall action of my application. Till now, I have got a specific code that catch the uninstall action and inflate an `Activity`. Here is the code:

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
android:name=".UninstallActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="package"  />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have created a simple `Activity` called `UninstallActivity` and It works fine. When the user try to uninstall the app this `Activity` has been inflated.

I am trying to listen on those intents with a `Receiver` instead of `Activity` but I have failed to get this action. My code is:

**Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".PackageUninstallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**PackageUninstallReceiver:**

```
public class PackageUninstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("uTag", "In the PackageUninstallReceiver onReceive()");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DELETE) && intent.getDataString().contains(context.getPackageName())) {
        Log.d("uTag", "Uninstallation is being happened....");
    }
}
}
```

First, is it possible to listen to this `Intent` with the receiver? 
If yes, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can not get uninstall action for same application.

Comment: @PankajKumar .. you can did this with `Activity` as the above code, I want to do it in the background with a `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Intent` used to start an `Activity` (in this case, an `Intent` to VIEW or DELETE a PACKAGE) is a completely different thing from a braodcast `Intent`. They share some of the same properties, but are still completely different things. a broadcast `Intent` will never start an `Activity` and an `Intent` used to start an `Activity` will never be seen by a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Therefore, the answer to your question

> First, is it possible to listen to this Intent with the receiver?

is "no".

Answer (score 1):

The actions you are listening are generic and could be applied in *any* context with a different schema. What you *should* be listening to is the package changing.

```
  <receiver android:name="PackageChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Comment: I only want to listen to the uninstall action not installing or replacing the Package. I have tried `PACKAGE_REMOVED` but it did not work

Comment: You cannot listen for the `PACKAGE_REMOVED` broadcast of your own application. This `Intent` is broadcast after your application has been uninstalled, so your code isn't there to receive it.

Comment: At no point has he said that this is listening for uninstallation of the same application.

Comment: @NickCardoso Actually the first sentence in the question is "I am trying to detect the uninstall action of my application." To me this means that OP is trying to detect the uninstallation of his own (ie: the same) application.

Comment: There is nothing to say it is the same application, you're just assuming lowly of his intelligence. He could well have an install manager managing a suite of apps. If you said "He might be trying to listen to the same application" you would be right. But at the moment you are just making assumptions and rudely commenting because you *assume* you are right.